# Xamarin Handler.Post does not invoke IRunnable.Run()

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, runnable

I am trying to run this Android code in Xamarin:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    int hours = seconds/3600;
    int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
    int secs = seconds%60;

    String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs);
    timeView.setText(time);
    if (running) {
        seconds++;
    }
    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

I have tried this in Xamarin;

```
Test newTest = new Test(this);
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.Post(newTest);
```

Test class is `IRunnable` as

```
public class Test : IRunnable
{
    MainActivity activity;
    public Test(MainActivity test)
    {
        activity = test;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return (IntPtr)0;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------->Run called<-----------------------");
        TextView stopWatch = activity.getTextView();
        int hour = activity.seconds / 3600;
        int minute = (activity.seconds % 3600) / 60;
        int sec = activity.seconds % 60;

        string time = string.Format("%d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, sec);
        stopWatch.Text = time;

        if (activity.running == true)
        {
            activity.seconds++;
        }

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.PostDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}
```

The program runs but `Handler` is not calling the `Run()` function. I am new to Xamarin. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a  typical error.
The hint is hidden in the Build Output.

> Type 'App1.Test' implements Android.Runtime.IJavaObject but does not inherit from Java.Lang.Object. It is not supported.

Everytime, you **implement a Java Interface**, you have to inherit from `Java.Lang.Object`.

```
public class Test : Java.Lang.Object, IRunnable
{
    // ...
}
```